# memory permutation random linq of very large list orderby

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing, sql-order-by, permutation

I am doing a permutation of a specific series of sequences that is 104 characters long. I was using plinq to generate the sequence but without a random order the results are never complex enough to be selected.

The problem is orderby with rnd.next and guid.newguid fills up memory and returns no results.

is there any solution to randomly selecting from a linq pattern in C#?

```
var query = 
             from sp1 in polar
                    ...
             from vp15 in polar                           
             where GetCompressionRatio(sp1+...+vp15)>1.5
             orderby rnd.Next(0, 100000000) * rnd.Next(0, 100000000)
             select sp1+...+vp15;


foreach (var element in query)
{
    //output
}
```

Comment: Question 1: You did declare rnd before query as such: Random rnd = new Random(); right?

Comment: Question 2: do you want to randomly select from a list (generated with linq) or do you want a randomized list returned by linq and then select from that randomly?

Comment: Question 3: "guid.newguid fills up memory and returns no results" , where is that guid.newguid() exactly?

Comment: GUID isn't the best thing to sort by...

Comment: @Andris Q1 Random rnd = new Random();

Comment: @Andris Q2 i was to access a permutation randomly i think it would take too much processing power to generate the list and then randomly select from it

Comment: @Andris Q3 i put orderby guid.newguid()

Comment: I don't see any reason why rnd.Next() would not work for this case, can you share the complete linq query code? Also, just use rnd.Next() without upper bounds and without multiply Next() by Next(), multiply to random numbers generated by the same algo will not "improve" the randomness...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to solve two very different problems with the same query. Even if there is a clever way to do it, I would suggest you take it one step at a time.

First, generate a non random permutation. 
Than, apply some random permutation algorithm on the previous result. You can try the very simple [Knuth Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle).

Your intention will be much more clear and the decomposition can give you significant advantages in testing and debugging.